# what is the period of this sinusoidal function funtion

Tags: signal-processing, periodic-functions

How can we find the fundamental period of this sinusoidal discrete function
$x(n) = 10\cos{(\frac{4n\pi}{31}+\frac{\pi}{5}})$

I tried using the formulae $\frac{2π}{\omega}$ and got the answer 31/2, but since the function is discrete shouldn't the period be a whole number??

Comment: we know that $ cos(u+2\pi ) = cos (u) $ for every 'u' so set $ u= \frac{4n \pi}{31}+ \frac{\pi}{5} $

Comment: Just because a signal is discrete does not mean that its period will be an integer. The discrete nature of the signal refers to the sampling of the signal and not its frequency/period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function has period $31/2$ just as you answered it yourself.  The period does not need to be an integer.